# How to solve this Google App Script error for a BigQuery job function?

Tags: google-bigquery

I found this script on stackoverflow and tried to run it but I get this referenceError. I want to use the format of this script to schedule my BigQuery scripts.

(Of course I have used real values instead of x's ;) )

ReferenceError: "BigQuery" is not defined. (line 20, file "Code")

```
    function saveQueryToTable() {
  var projectId = 'xxxxx';
  var datasetId = 'xxxxx';
  var tableId = 'xxxxx';
  var job = {
    configuration: {
      query: {
        query: 'SELECT TOP(word, 300) AS word, COUNT(*) AS word_count' +
               'FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare' +
               'WHERE LENGTH(word) > 10;',
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        }
      }
    }
  };

var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId);
  Logger.log(queryResults.status);
}
```

Comment: Do you have the `BigQuery` service enable?...check the image for reference https://i.stack.imgur.com/McmWw.png

Comment: @Hackerman Thanks! That was indeed the problem. Now the script runs without generating errors, but it is not generating a result in BQ. Any idea why?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution. The whole query needs to be in one string.

Comment: Just for the record, your query was ok, but, on this way `query: 'SELECT TOP(word, 300) AS word, COUNT(*) AS word_count' +
               ' FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare' +
               ' WHERE LENGTH(word) > 10;'`...you just need an extra space on `FROM` and `WHERE`